# Что не так с этим кодом (он должен немного изменить html-страницу)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Приведенный ниже код должен создать список с содержимым, которое вводит пользователь.

```
function d_list() {
    let content = prompt()
    let elem;
    elem = '<ul>'
    while (content) {
        content = prompt()
        elem.innerHTML =+ '<li>' + content + '</li>'
    }
    elem =+ '</ul>'
    return elem;
}

let list = d_list()
let div = document.querySelector('.dyn_list')
div.append(list)
```

Приведенный ниже код должен создать список из заданного объекта ....................................... .....................................................................

```
    let data = {
        "Рыбы": {
            "форель": {},
            "лосось": {}
        },
        "Деревья": {
            "Огромные": {
            "секвойя": {},
            "дуб": {}
        },
        "Цветковые": {
            "яблоня": {},
            "магнолия": {}
        }
    }
    };
```

Есть код, который создает список списков ........................................ ...............

```
    function createTree(container, data) {
        container.innerHTML = '<ul>'

        for (let things in data) {
            things.innerHTML = '<ul>'
            if (things.hasOwnProperty()) {
                for (let t in things) {
                    t.innerHTML = t
                }
        } else {
            things.innerHTML = things
    }
        things.innerHTML += '</ul>'
    }

        container.innerHTML += '</ul>'
    }   

    let container = document.getElementById('container');
    createTree(container, data);
```

Comment: `elem = '<ul>'` и дальше `elem.innerHTML`.. Вы записываете простую строку, откуда у неё innerHTML взяться? Либо собирайте строку и её вставляйте, либо создавайте ul через `document.createElement('ul');` и, соответственно, li и остальное аналогичным образом создавать

Comment: Понял, исправил, спасибо, а  что со второй задачкой не подскажете?

Comment: то же самое, ты пытаешься добавить свойство в строку `t` вместо `things`, которая тоже строка и вместо нее надо было добавлять в `container.innerHTML` все, который на самом деле строка со всем `html`

Comment: Спасибо, понял, исправлю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В обоих примерах перепутаны места где со строкой производятся действия как с элементом:

1. `elem.innerHTML =+ '<li>' + content + '</li>'`: elem - это строка, поэтому тут недолжно было быть `innerHTML`
2. `div.append(list)` - так как `d_list` возвращает строку, а не элемент, вместо `.append` тут как раз можно было использовать `.innerHTML`.

---

В цикле `for..in` проход идет по ключам, ключами в данном случае могут быть только строки, поэтому и тут

```
for (let things in data) {
```

и тут

```
for (let t in things) {
```

`things` и `t` - являются строками, и как и в предыдущем примере в дальнейшем у них идет обращение к `.innerHTML`

Вместо этого, необходимо было менять `.innerHTML` единственного элемента `container`